# Using MPI on a single Raspberry-Pi

Tags: c++, multithreading, mpi, raspberry-pi3, fftw

I am working on an application (in C++) which involves several independent operations ([FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) + signal processing) on data arrays.
Array sizes can be either 512 or 1024 (yet to decide), and the data type is double.

I am hoping to make those independent operations parallalized to get the best out of the Pi.
Obvious thing I would have done in the past is using pthreads.

However, (unfortunately :) ) I learned about MPI recently and I wonder whether I should use it here instead of good old threads.
Obviously MPI would be the way to go if I have a device cluster (that's what I get when I search the internet).

But is MPI still a good choice in my situation, where there is just one device? (and specially when that device is a Raspberry-Pi).

(If the answer to above is "no", does that mean MPI is a bad choice in general when there is only one computer?)

Comment: If you know `pthreads` and don't envisage going to a multi-raspberry cluster, I am not sure I personally see any benefit of using `MPI`, but that's just my 2 pence worth!

Comment: Yeah, I'd say that if you are running (a) completely independent tasks, (b) on a single node, there are simpler ways to do what you want to do - you can just run multiple copies of the program at once, either by hand or using a tool like [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

Comment: One of the things that MPI effectively enforces is data localization. This can be important on single-node systems with multiple sockets (not the case with a Pi). Data within MPI programs is not shared by default, whereas with threads it is.

One thing you may have to be careful of with FFTW, though, is that you have to jump through a hoop or two to make sure it is thread-safe. If you are using MPI for your parallelization, you don't have to worry about thread safety.

I also second the comment of looking at GNU Parallel.

Answer (score 1):

MPI can be an awesome choice depending on how much work can be done per unit communication. That's how I would consider MPI or not.

I am coauthor of an MRI simulation framework. There we deal with individual "macro" spins, which can be dealt with generally as spatially non-interacting. This allows one to do poor man's parallelisation on every single spin and the local bloch equations. So a lot of physics for very little communication. Even on a single device it can perform as well as pthreads.

However on the other side of the spectrum I's see massive parallel matrix inversion as done with SCALAPACK. There you'll find a lot of communication per unit calculation. That's where there is not a chance in the world you could compete with pthreads.

Even if you were going to use a pi cluster, you'd use both MPI and pthreads in such cases and might not be able to break even, as the 100Mbit network has significant latency issues.
There are single board machines with 1Gb/s network and stronger fp performance as raspberry pi, where the cost of communication might be worth it.

tldr: For MPI to make sense one wants `computation/communication >> 1`.